# Remote debug Gogland halting

Tags: debugging, go, remote-debugging, delve, goland

I need help with Remote debugging in Gogland with Delve.

I try to debug my app on remote server with IDE Goglang (1.0 EAP) and dlv link: https://github.com/derekparker/delve/

Install and try remote debug simple program:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello world")
    for i:=uint(0); i< 10; i++{
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

Firstly, start dlv on remote host (output from console):

```
$ dlv debug --headless --listen=:2345 --log --api-version=2
API server listening at: [::]:2345
```

Then, start remote debug in IDE:

Out from remote host console:

```
2017/07/20 17:23:24 debugger.go:504: continuing
2017/07/20 17:23:24 debugger.go:493: halting
2017/07/20 17:23:24 debugger.go:347: created breakpoint: &api.Breakpoint{ID:1, Name:"", Addr:0x47bb52, File:"/....../hello/hello.go", Line:6, FunctionName:"main.main", Cond:"", Tracepoint:false, Goroutine:false, Stacktrace:0, Variables:[]string(nil), LoadArgs:(*api.LoadConfig)(nil), LoadLocals:(*api.LoadConfig)(nil), HitCount:map[string]uint64{}, TotalHitCount:0x0}
2017/07/20 17:23:24 debugger.go:504: continuing
2017/07/20 17:23:28 debugger.go:516: nexting
hello world
2017/07/20 17:23:28 debugger.go:516: nexting
2017/07/20 17:23:29 debugger.go:516: nexting
0
2017/07/20 17:23:29 debugger.go:516: nexting
02017/07/20 17:23:29 debugger.go:516: nexting
2017/07/20 17:23:29 debugger.go:516: nexting
1
2017/07/20 17:23:29 debugger.go:516: nexting
12017/07/20 17:23:30 debugger.go:516: nexting
2017/07/20 17:23:30 debugger.go:516: nexting
2
2017/07/20 17:23:30 debugger.go:516: nexting
42017/07/20 17:23:30 debugger.go:516: nexting
2017/07/20 17:23:30 debugger.go:516: nexting
3
2017/07/20 17:23:30 debugger.go:516: nexting
92017/07/20 17:23:31 debugger.go:516: nexting
2017/07/20 17:23:31 debugger.go:516: nexting
4
2017/07/20 17:23:31 debugger.go:516: nexting
162017/07/20 17:23:31 debugger.go:516: nexting
2017/07/20 17:23:31 debugger.go:516: nexting
5
2017/07/20 17:23:32 debugger.go:516: nexting
252017/07/20 17:23:32 debugger.go:516: nexting
2017/07/20 17:23:32 debugger.go:516: nexting
6
2017/07/20 17:23:32 debugger.go:516: nexting
362017/07/20 17:23:32 debugger.go:516: nexting
2017/07/20 17:23:32 debugger.go:516: nexting
7
2017/07/20 17:23:33 debugger.go:516: nexting
492017/07/20 17:23:33 debugger.go:516: nexting
2017/07/20 17:23:33 debugger.go:516: nexting
8
2017/07/20 17:23:34 debugger.go:516: nexting
642017/07/20 17:23:34 debugger.go:516: nexting
2017/07/20 17:23:34 debugger.go:516: nexting
9
2017/07/20 17:23:34 debugger.go:516: nexting
812017/07/20 17:23:34 debugger.go:516: nexting
2017/07/20 17:23:35 debugger.go:516: nexting
2017/07/20 17:23:35 debugger.go:516: nexting
```

Everything works as I expected (breakpoint, F7, F8 and etc.)

Then i try to debug My APP:

```
dlv debug --headless --listen=:2345 --log --api-version=2 -- --v --console
2017/07/20 17:26:51 debugger.go:97: launching process with args: [/home/...../debug --v --console]
API server listening at: [::]:2345
```

IDE start

Output:

```
2017/07/20 17:26:55 debugger.go:493: halting
2017/07/20 17:26:55 debugger.go:347: created breakpoint: &api.Breakpoint{ID:1, Name:"", Addr:0x687a73, File:"/home/..........go", Line:136, FunctionName:"main.main", Cond:"", Tracepoint:false, Goroutine:false, Stacktrace:0, Variables:[]string(nil), LoadArgs:(*api.LoadConfig)(nil), LoadLocals:(*api.LoadConfig)(nil), HitCount:map[string]uint64{}, TotalHitCount:0x0}
2017/07/20 17:26:55 debugger.go:347: created breakpoint: &api.Breakpoint{ID:2, Name:"", Addr:0x6869b2, File:"/home/..........go", Line:66, FunctionName:"main.main", Cond:"", Tracepoint:false, Goroutine:false, Stacktrace:0, Variables:[]string(nil), LoadArgs:(*api.LoadConfig)(nil), LoadLocals:(*api.LoadConfig)(nil), HitCount:map[string]uint64{}, TotalHitCount:0x0}
2017/07/20 17:26:55 debugger.go:504: continuing
2017/07/20 17:26:55 debugger.go:347: created breakpoint: &api.Breakpoint{ID:3, Name:"", Addr:0x687d33, File:"/home/........go", Line:143, FunctionName:"main.main", Cond:"", Tracepoint:false, Goroutine:false, Stacktrace:0, Variables:[]string(nil), LoadArgs:(*api.LoadConfig)(nil), LoadLocals:(*api.LoadConfig)(nil), HitCount:map[string]uint64{}, TotalHitCount:0x0}
2017/07/20 17:26:55 debugger.go:504: continuing
2017/07/20 17:26:57 debugger.go:516: nexting
```

IDE debug does not work (hangs up). If I don't use breakpoints app start and run like a usual (RUN).

I think this line is the reason for my problem:

**2017/07/20 17:26:45 debugger.go:493: halting**

Why does it arise ?? Maybe I have a complicated utility structure (the main package is divided into several files, of course there are external plug-in packages, etc.) or something else?

BUT (! the most interesting !) is that if you join a remote server not through the IDE, but through the console, then debugging works on a simple example and in the case of my utility:

```
dlv connect HOSTNAME:2345
Type 'help' for list of commands.
(dlv) b ********.go:137
Breakpoint 1 set at 0x687a86 for main.main() /home/*************.go:137
(dlv) c
> main.main() /home/***************************.go:137 (hits goroutine(1):1 total:1) (PC: 0x687a86)
(dlv) n
```

Output:

```
$ dlv debug --headless --listen=:2345 --log --api-version=2 -- --v --console
2017/07/20 17:37:37 debugger.go:97: launching process with args: [/home/*****************/debug --v --console]
API server listening at: [::]:2345
2017/07/20 17:38:27 debugger.go:347: created breakpoint: &api.Breakpoint{ID:1, Name:"", Addr:0x687a86, File:"/home/*******************.go", Line:137, FunctionName:"main.main", Cond:"", Tracepoint:false, Goroutine:false, Stacktrace:0, Variables:[]string(nil), LoadArgs:(*api.LoadConfig)(nil), LoadLocals:(*api.LoadConfig)(nil), HitCount:map[string]uint64{}, TotalHitCount:0x0}
2017/07/20 17:38:35 debugger.go:504: continuing
2017/07/20 17:38:39 debugger.go:516: nexting
```

Those. There is a suspicion of an error in the IDE, or I'm doing something wrong :).

I also try debug with dlv exec (already build app) and other command.

Thanks for the time given to the question, I really hope for help.

P.S. I will also be glad to know what else you can use for remote debugging for GO app.

P.P.S. I tried to make remote debugging in Atom.io and in VS code
In Atom, work only locale debug with dlv.

In VS code the local debugger works through dlv + remote debugger works, but breakpoints doesn't work !!! Those. VS Code is also not an option.
Configuring VS Code (launch.json)

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "REMOTE",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "remote",
            "remotePath": "{workspaceRoot}",
            "port": 2345,
            "host": "REMOTE_HOST_NAME",
            "program":  "${workspaceRoot}", //"${fileDirname}",
            "env": {},
            "args": ["--v", "--console"],
            "showLog": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: For Gogland, please add "#com.goide.dlv.DlvVm" (without quotes) to Help | Debug Log Settings... then try and debug the application and add the logs here. You can find the logs via Help | Show logs in... and see idea.log. Alternatively, you can open the issue on the tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/Go and upload the log there

Comment: @dlsniper , LOG file from IDE:http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=03959827677220728410

Comment: As far as I can tell, delve just exists the process and that's it. Are you running the latest Go (1.8.3)? What is the host of the debugged process? How do you build/start the debugged app? I can't understand if the simple app works or not? If it does and if it doesn't, can you post the FULL logs from the IDE? If the actual app doesn't work, probably there's some other reason behind it, but w/o a way to reproduce it in a sample there's not much I can do about it. Sadly these kind of things are not suitable to be solved on StackOverflow.

Comment: Simple app works (remote debug). But my app doesn't work, halting without any error msg.

Comment: Well, it could be a bug in the IDE, debugger or Go. Without a way to reproduce it I don't have any magical way to figure it out. I've asked you a bunch of questions and you responded to none. Imagine you would have to make sense of this issue and our roles would be reversed. How would you identify the problem?

Comment: I certainly agree with you. At the moment I'm not ready to provide an example on which the debugger does not work. The question asked here because thought that someone might already have faced this problem or similar problem.

Comment: I'm trying to make and publish an example project that can demonstrate this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was IDE based. Solved in version: 
Build: EAP 12, 172.3757.46
Released: Aug 11, 2017